# Why is backspace allowed in my jQuery whether I filter it out or not?

Tags: jquery, ascii, keypress, backspace

I've got this jQuery:

```
$(document).on("keypress", '[id*=Float]', function (e) { 
    //only allow 1..9 (48..57), '.' (46), and backspace (8)
    var k = e.which;
    if (k === 8 || k === 46) return;
    if (k < 48 || k > 57) { e.preventDefault(); }
});
```

...working on this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtbxFloat">
</br>
<input type="text" id="txtbxHopeFloats">
</br>
<input type="text" id="txtbxFloatingFreeAsABird">
```

It can be fiddled with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/jy6t5oru/22/)

It does what the comments say/what I want. However, so does this:

```
$(document).on("keypress", '[id*=Float]', function (e) { 
    //only allow 1..9 (48..57), '.' (46), and backspace (8)
    var k = e.which;
    if (k === 46) return;
    if (k < 48 || k > 57) { e.preventDefault(); }
});
```

IOW, the "8" (backspace) is allowed in either case. Why? I guess it's not a problem for me at the moment, but what if I really *wanted* to prevent a backspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to prevent backspace, you should unbind the default event and re-attach a 'new' version of it.

Try something like:

```
$(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function (event) {
    var doPrevent = false;
    if (event.keyCode === 8) {
        var d = event.srcElement || event.target;
        if ((d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' && (d.type.toUpperCase() === 'TEXT' || d.type.toUpperCase() === 'PASSWORD' || d.type.toUpperCase() === 'FILE')) || d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TEXTAREA') {
            doPrevent = d.readOnly || d.disabled;
        }
        else {
            doPrevent = true;
        }
    }

    if (doPrevent) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // rest of code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `keypress` is not triggered when using backspace because  `keypress` fires when actual character(any printing key) is being entered. Backspace doesn't enter any character. While `keydown` fires if any key is pressed. That's why `keydown` should work to prevent backspace.

This is what is mentioned in [Jquery spec](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, **except that modifier and non-printing keys** such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger keydown events but not keypress events.** Other differences between the two events may arise depending on platform and browser.

Comment: No, actually, using keydown prevents both '.' and backspace, which I want to retain (I just changed my fiddle event from keypress to keydown and found that to be the case).

Comment: oh..ok. But I think you can keep your current `keypress` code as it is and add separate `keydown` handler just to prevent backspace

Comment: my answer was more inclined towards explaining why backspace and other non-printing keys don't trigger `keypress`, which I though was the root cause of your question :)

Comment: Well, the keypress code is working, as noted; I was just curious how to solve the problem if/when I wanted to filter out the backspace (which I don't).

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution would be to use `keydown` instead of `keypress`.

The keyboard events occur in this order: `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`.

```
$(document).on("keydown", '[id*=Float]', function (e) { 
    //only allow 1..9 (48..57), '.' (46), and backspace (8)
    var k = e.which;
    if (k === 46) return;
    if (k < 48 || k > 57) { e.preventDefault(); }
});
```

Comment: Using the keydown event, the '.' IS filtered out; I want to retain it (and backspace, too).